# Where should randomness come from in the Monte Carlo simulations?

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

Suppose that I want to check how good OLS works in some specific environment using Monte Carlo. I can simulate $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$. What should I do in Monte Carlo simulations, do I simulate the whole model on each replication, or do I simulate only $\epsilon$ in each replication, while $X$ is the same across all replications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would have some distributional specification for $X$ and re-simulate $X$ on each monte carlo iteration as apposed to using the same $X$ on each iteration.  This way the monte carlo simulation would apply to the entire population of $(y,X)$ as apposed to just one finite sample.  Also, you have to have some specification for $\epsilon$.  Lets say, $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.  Here is how I would do it in R (pseudo code).

```
b.estimates=matrix(NA,nrow=b,ncol=k) #k is the number of variables 
for(i in 1:b)
{
   #Simulate X here
   e = rnorm(n,0,sd=sigma)
   y= X%*%Beta +e
   b.estimates[i,]=solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%y  
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm asking because I have a problem set, where professor asks to simulate $X$ ones and then to create randomness in Monte Carlo using $\epsilon$, that is in each iteration, only $\epsilon$ and $Y$ are resimulated. I was wondering whether this was just a particular problem, and whether I should do Monte Carlo this way in practice. Drawing $(\epsilon,X)$ in each iteration makes more sense to me as well.